# compare 2 JSONObjects without regard to value types

Tags: java, jettison

I'm using Jettison to make JSONObjects out of some Strings

I want to get a list of all the keys in one JSONObject (j1) and compare the values to the values attached to the keys in the other JSONObject (j2).

I'm trying to create something where I don't care about the type of the value since the values are character strings and ints and who knows what else.

So I'm doing something like:

I want to do something like

```
Object o1 = j1.get("key")
Object o2 = j2.get("key")
```

What can I convert o1 & o2 into so I can compare their values?  JSONObject?  What if the values are JSONArrays?

I have tried JSONObject and I get a

```
"ClassCastException org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject$Null cannot be cast to org.codehaus.jettison.json."
```

when I have:

```
{"key1":null, .....
```

What options do I have with that?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are comparing the values for equality (and not, say, with respect to some ordering), you can just use `Object.equals`:

```
o1.equals(o2)
```

since the signature, even in classes extending `Object`, is

```
public boolean equals(Object other)
```

so you can compare any object to any other, no conversion or explicit casting needed (implementations of `equals` will likely do casting internally, though).

If one or both of them can be null, you can use `java.util.Objects.equals` to avoid the potential NPE:

```
Objects.equals(o1, o2)
```

Comment: excellent!  that works.  but what can i do if one JSONObject has {"key1":"100"   and the other has {"key1":100 (one has a String value and one has an int value) ?